# Restrict internet exposure to a Google Cloud bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

As far as i see, IAM/ACl polices only restrict permission access to GCP bucket.
I want to control the internet exposure of my bucket - having it blocked to all ip's or allowing only set of ip (allowlist).
As far as i see, its possible with vpc service control ([VPC Service Controls](https://www.praetorian.com/blog/cloud-data-exfiltration-via-gcp-storage-buckets-and-how-to-prevent-it/#:%7E:text=Use%20VPC%20Service%20Controls%20to%20restrict%20access%20to,a%20VPC%20and%20help%20mitigate%20data%20exfiltration%20risks.))
is there a built in feature in gcp cloud storage that gives this functionality? or its possible only with vpc service control?

Comment: It's weird to use a public cloud service and to want to make it private. What's your use case? What's your risk? From what do you want to protect your data?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a documentation about [Public Access Prevention](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/public-access-prevention) setting that can provide an overview on how to do the public access prevention. If this documentation meets the requirements you need, then you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-public-access-prevention#pap-bucket) for the steps to enforce public access prevention.